# Drop down navigation menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, prototypejs

I am new to rails and I am trying to create a drop down menu in a vertical menu. Ideally I would like for it to simply expand and show more options in the menu when clicked. I have been googling around and I cannot seem to find a good way to do this? What is the best way to do it?  I was trying to used Prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start: This is more or less a UI thing, so I wouldn't describe it as a rails specific question.

What you'd like to know is pretty vague, but the goal could be refined easily. You need to know what browsers you want to support, if it *needs* to be javascript based, if it needs to be particularly scalable (Does it need a single menu, or will it need submenus now or eventually?), and I imagine you can think of a few relevant things as well.

Just outline what your working version would be like. Find samples and figure out which one suits you. From there, you could begin singling out useful resources for figuring out how to move forward.

Twitter's bootstrap-dropdown.js offers a [pretty neat dropdown menu](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdown) you could learn from if you're not glued to prototype.

Depending on how you plan to use the menu you end up using/adapting/building, you could implement it several ways in rails. It could be a navigation component that is called as required and passed an array of links, or it could be an somewhat static include that is part of a template. That part won't have much to do with the implementation of the menu's markup and scripting though, I think.